# How long has The Knight in the Panther's Skin been considered a Georgian national epic?

Tags: history-of-literature, georgian-language, shota-rustaveli, knight-in-the-panthers-skin

[Shota Rustaveli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shota_Rustaveli) (c. 1160 – after c. 1220) was the author of "*The Knight in the Panther's Skin*, which is considered to be a Georgian national epic poem." The Wikipedia article about [*The Knight in the Panther's Skin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Knight_in_the_Panther%27s_Skin) tells us that

> Until the early 20th century, a copy of this poem was part of the dowry of every bride.

The German Wikipedia article about the epic, [*Der Recke im Tigerfell*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Recke_im_Tigerfell) tells us that

> The poem is required reading in Georgian schools and does not pose great linguistic difficulties because the Georgian language has not evolved as much as, for example, German from Middle High German.

According to the French Wikipedia article about the author ([Chota Roustavéli](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chota_Roustav%C3%A9li)),

> Each Georgian family possesses at least one illustrated edition of the book, and in schools, pupils are required to learn a number of its quatrains.

Wikipedia notes about its [values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Knight_in_the_Panther%27s_Skin#Values) that

> The poem also shows an admiration for the woman and demands for gender equality. (…) Slavery is also condemned in the poem.

According to the English Wikipedia article, "Two folios of this text, dating from the 16th century, are located in the Institute of Manuscripts of Georgia in Tbilisi", but according to the [German Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Recke_im_Tigerfell#%C3%9Cberlieferung), the oldest manuscripts date from the 17th century. It was first printed in 1712 by order of king [Vakhtang VI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vakhtang_VI_of_Kartli), also known as "Vakhtang the Scholar". (He added his own scholarly commentaries.)

What I have not found in the articles linked in the above paragraphs is when *The Knight in the Panther's Skin* acquired the status of national epic. The Kingdom of Georgia reached its [Golden Age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Georgia#Golden_age) from the 11th till the early 14th century. The bubonic plague and Mongol invasions were two important reasons for the decline of the kingdom, which eventually disintegrated into smaller states. There are several time periods during which the epic may have become accepted as a national epic, for example:

- the period that led up to the creation of the oldest extant manuscripts (16th or 17th century),
- around the time when the epic was first printed by order of king Vakhtang VI (1712),
- at some point in the 19th century, during which movements of romantic nationalism in many European countries looked to the past to identify national heroes and national epics (or create national epics, such as the [*Kalevipoeg* in Estonia](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/20229/2191)).

Is there any literary or historical evidence that can help determine when *The Knight in the Panther's Skin* was first considered a national epic? Answering this question may help us understand how Georgians used literature to shape their national identity.